# @Cacheable is not able to update

Tags: spring, hazelcast

In spring framework we have @Cacheable to cache data right. Now my requirement is i want to retrieve  all data form database by using Get method.

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getUploadData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<Ticket>> getUploadFileData() throws IOException {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(ticketBookingService.getFileUploadData(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Service

```
@Cacheable(value="ticketsCache")
public List<Ticket> getFileUploadData() {
    List<Ticket> listOfData = (List<Ticket>) ticketBookingDao.findAll();
    return listOfData;
}
```

}

output:
 [click image here to check output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElCHA.png)

http://localhost:8080/api/tickets/getUploadData

```
[{"ticketId":1,"passengerName":"Sean","bookingDate":1502649000000,"sourceStation":"Pune","destStation":"Mumbai","email":"sean.s2017@yahoo.com"},{"ticketId":2,"passengerName":"Raj","bookingDate":1502476200000,"sourceStation":"Chennai","destStation":"Mumbai","email":"raj.s2007@siffy.com"},{"ticketId":3,"passengerName":"Martin","bookingDate":1502735400000,"sourceStation":"Delhi","destStation":"Mumbai","email":"martin.s2001@xyz.com"},{"ticketId":4,"passengerName":"John","bookingDate":1503253800000,"sourceStation":"Chennai","destStation":"Mumbai","email":"john.s2011@yahoo.com"}]
```

Now i will do get and put operation by ticketid.

Get:
Controller:

```
    @GetMapping(value="/ticket/{ticketId}")
public Ticket getTicketById(@PathVariable("ticketId")Integer ticketId){
    return ticketBookingService.getTicketById(ticketId);
}
```

Service:

```
    @Cacheable(value="ticketsCache",key="#ticketId",unless="#result==null")
public Ticket getTicketById(Integer ticketId) {
    return ticketBookingDao.findOne(ticketId);
}
```

http://localhost:8080/api/tickets/ticket/1

{"ticketId":1,"passengerName":"Sean","bookingDate":1502649000000,"sourceStation":"Pune","destStation":"Mumbai","email":"sean.s2017@yahoo.com"}

Now when i do update email by using ticketid:

Put: controller

```
    @PutMapping(value="/ticket/{ticketId}/{newEmail:.+}")
public Ticket updateTicket(@PathVariable("ticketId")Integer ticketId,@PathVariable("newEmail")String newEmail){
    return ticketBookingService.updateTicket(ticketId,newEmail);
}
```

Service:

```
@CachePut(value="ticketsCache",key="#ticketId")
public Ticket updateTicket(Integer ticketId, String newEmail) {
    Ticket upadedTicket = null;
    Ticket ticketFromDb = ticketBookingDao.findOne(ticketId);
    if(ticketFromDb != null){
        ticketFromDb.setEmail(newEmail);
        upadedTicket = ticketBookingDao.save(ticketFromDb); 
    }
    return upadedTicket;
}
```

http://localhost:8080/api/tickets/ticket/1/abcd@yahoo.com

```
{
"ticketId": 1,
"passengerName": "Sean",
"bookingDate": 1502649000000,
"sourceStation": "Pune",
"destStation": "Mumbai",
"email": "abcd@yahoo.com"
```

}

Now when get data by using ID changes are updating.

http://localhost:8080/api/tickets/ticket/1

```
{"ticketId":1,"passengerName":"Sean","bookingDate":1502649000000,"sourceStation":"Pune","destStation":"Mumbai","email":"abcd@yahoo.com"}
```

Now my Question is if i try to get all data by using above first URL my changes are not reflecting.

http://localhost:8080/api/tickets/getUploadData

```
[{"ticketId":1,"passengerName":"Sean","bookingDate":1502649000000,"sourceStation":"Pune","destStation":"Mumbai","email":"sean.s2017@yahoo.com"},{"ticketId":2,"passengerName":"Raj","bookingDate":1502476200000,"sourceStation":"Chennai","destStation":"Mumbai","email":"raj.s2007@siffy.com"},{"ticketId":3,"passengerName":"Martin","bookingDate":1502735400000,"sourceStation":"Delhi","destStation":"Mumbai","email":"martin.s2001@xyz.com"},{"ticketId":4,"passengerName":"John","bookingDate":1503253800000,"sourceStation":"Chennai","destStation":"Mumbai","email":"john.s2011@yahoo.com"}]
```

Suggest me how to reslove this issue

Comment: What kind of database ? MySql ? PostGres ? Spring `@Cacheable` with Hazelcast uses an [IMap](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.0/javadoc/com/hazelcast/map/IMap.html), but how this could be updated behind the scenes depends on the database

Comment: And why should it? You are caching different things. The first caches a list of all tickets, the second only a ticket. The caching mechanism will store the result of the method call NOT the individual elemens thereof. If you want to have automatic updates etc. integrate te cache with your persistency layer, instead of doing this.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot *bulk update* the cache with Spring.

Please check the following [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/19777) - closed with status *declined*:

> Thanks for creating the issue but I am not keen to add this extra complexity to the cache abstraction. It is not meant to manage state for you (the next logical step if we allow this is that we have to keep the returned list in sync with each item). And if we don't we are inconsistent and we merely provide a way to talk to the cache using annotations. That's not very helpful.
>
> Back to your example, this is typically what a second level cache is meant to do for you. This is not in the scope of the cache abstraction.