# Hazelcast not working for insert and update

Tags: hazelcast

I have this this method for save and update student but whenever I save student into database and hit getAllStudent it dosen't get back the last student I already have saved ?
ANy help?

```
@CachePut(cacheNames="studentCache")
public StudentDTO save (StudentDTO  studentDTo)
{
Student student=studentRepository.save().map
return studentMapper.toDto(student);
}

@override
@Transactional
@Cacheable
public Page(StudentDTO>findALL(Pageable p)
{

return studentRepository.findAll(pagebale).map(mapper::toDTO);
}
```

I understand that I can do clear cache whenever I create or update Student

```
@CacheEvict(value = "users", allEntries=true) 
Student create(Student student) {
    userStudent.create(student)
}
```

But I want to avoid that

Comment: First, what is "Haselcash" ?

Comment: Haselcash is a HazelCast

Answer (score 1):

Your `save` is caching singletons, `findAll` is caching collections. As far as the cache manager is concerned, there are two different things, updating one won't update the other.

Comment: I understand so what is the solution ?

Comment: Probably that's a question on it's own -- but I think you're asking too much of a cache manager to expect it do cascading deletes. Coding it yourself to interact with the cache manager's caches would not seem good design. See the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60912349/cacheable-is-not-able-to-update) also.

Comment: Thanks ,can this work on hibernate second level cache?

Comment: Unlikely. The design is wrong. Try asking a separate question, the cache manager is doing what it's support to do.

Comment: Yes, this works on Hibernate L2 cache because Hibernate knows the key of the cached value. This fails in Spring Cache because of the reason Neil provided

See my related answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60912349/cacheable-is-not-able-to-update/60913055#60913055